# shorten indices of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

being X_mean a pandas dataframe how can I optimize the following piece of code?
I want to "shorten" the index of the dataframe...

```
a=[]
for i in range(0,len(X_mean.index)):
    a.append(X_mean.index[i][0:-2])
X_mean.index = a
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [indexing with str](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#indexing-with-str):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3]}, index=['aatfd','sgefds','dsd'])
print (df)
        a
aatfd   1
sgefds  2
dsd     3

df.index = df.index.str[:-2]
print (df)
      a
aat   1
sgef  2
d     3
```